# Extract first number value from string sql

Tags: sql, string, sql-server-2008

I have found many answers that have pointed me on the right track for what I want, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26732633/4027761).

However, if I had a string like "this attachment will be 22 in. x 15 in. long" I would want to grab "22" (the first int value in the string). Also, I won't know how large (# of characters) the int value will be so I'll need to find the WHOLE first int value until the next special character/space in the string.

Any idea how I can go about doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Extract substring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650880/sql-extract-substring)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there really is a number in the string, you can use `patindex()`:

```
select left(s, patindex('%[^0-9]%', s) - 1)
from (select substring(col, patindex('%[0-9]%', col), len(col)) as s
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: That's it! However, I won't know the length argument in the substring syntax and would need the code to calculate that as well. Basically, I want it to grab the first WHOLE int (and possible decimal) value until the next special character/value (spaces, colons, semi-colons, hyphens, etc.) but ignore periods too so I can use decimal values.

Comment: Figured it out! Just simply had to use the LEN function on top of the PATINDEX function for the Length argument `select SUBSTRING(col, patindex('%[0-9]%', col), len(patindex('%[0-9]%', col))) as s from t`. Thanks for all your help, Gordon! :)