# how to extract address number from string in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have address in sql column which also contain possible door no, address and postcode i.e. as following format

```
120 westminister way Road, London (NW10 5NQ)
5 westminister way Road, London (NW10 5NQ)
```

I need to extract door no and address in two separate columns. I have tried to use PATINDEX '%[0-9]%' but i couldn't figure out of integer LEN

```
select 
  PostCode = iif(charindex('(',[address]) > 1, REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([address]),2, CHARINDEX('(', REVERSE([address]))-2)),'')
  ,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', [address]) DoorNoIndex
  ,SUBSTRING([address],PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', [address]), 2) DoorNo
  ,LEN( PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', [address])) doorNoLength
```

### output expected

```
i) door no 120
2) door no 5
```

Comment: As a human, I can't figure out what number in your text is the door number, so how do you expect SQL Server to do that?

Comment: Could you please share the desired output? :)

Comment: if I get first number in string and minus the post code that will be enough for me

Comment: i have updated expected output

Comment: for now just number will do for me... in other word if i know length of number in string, i can use substring to extract out

Comment: This answer will fix your problem: [Extract first number value from string sql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32726173/2794280)

Comment: see this line SUBSTRING([address],PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', [Land Description]), 2) DoorNo2 do job for me as far as I know length of number in string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the door number always in the begining of the string, so you can simply do

```
DECLARE @Temp AS TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY,Data nvarchar(100))
INSERT INTO @Temp
SELECT N'120 westminister way Road, London (NW10 5NQ)' UNION ALL
SELECT N'5 westminister way Road, London (NW10 5NQ)';

SELECT ID,
       'Door No: ' + LEFT(Data, PATINDEX('%[a-z]%', Data) -2) DoorNumber
FROM @Temp;
```

Or

```
SELECT ID,
       'Door No: ' + LEFT(Data, CHARINDEX(' ', Data) -1) DoorNumber
FROM @Temp;
```

**Returns:**

```
+----+--------------+
| ID |  DoorNumber  |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | Door No: 120 |
|  2 | Door No: 5   |
+----+--------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
DECLARE @Temp AS TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY,Data nvarchar(100))
INSERT INTO @Temp
SELECT '120 westminister way Road, London (NW10 5NQ)' UNION ALL
SELECT '5 westminister way Road, London (NW10 5NQ)'

;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT  ID,
        Split.a.value('.','nvarchar(1000)') AS Data,
        ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS rnk
FROM(
        SELECT ID,CAST('<S>'+REPLACE(Data,' ','</S><S>')+'</S>' AS XML) Data
         FROM @Temp
    )dt 
    CROSS APPLY Data.nodes('S') AS Split(a)
)
SELECT ID, 'Door No: '+CAST(Data AS VARCHAR(10))  AS [Output expected]
FROM CTE WHERE rnk=1
```

Result

```
ID  Output expected
------------------
1   Door No: 120
2   Door No: 5
```

Comment: This seems way to slow and complicated. Generating 14 rows of data and then selecting the first value each set may work with few rows, but it is really ineffective

Answer (score 2):

You can try your query as shown below.

```
create table #temp (id int identity(1,1), DoorNo Varchar(50))
insert into #temp (DoorNo) select * from (
select 'Door No:' + substring('120 westminister way Road, London (NW10 5NQ)',1,PATINDEX('% %','120 westminister way Road, London (NW10 5NQ)')) as doorno
UNION ALL
select 'Door No:' + substring('5 westminister way Road, London (NW10 5NQ)',1,PATINDEX('% %','5 westminister way Road, London (NW10 5NQ)')) as doorno
)a

select * from #temp
drop table #temp
```

The output will be as shown below

```
id  DoorNo
1   Door No:120 
2   Door No:5
```

Hope this is helpfull to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 /* IF YOUR ADDRESS ARE ALWAYS START WITH DOOR NO, YOU CAN USE FOLLOWING FUNCTION
    TO GET DOOR NO /*

  CREATE TABLE DEMO
  (
        ID INT NOT NULL,
        ADDRESS VARCHAR(100)
  );

   INSERT DEMO
   VALUES(112, '120 westminister way Road, London (NW10 5NQ)');

   SELECT DBO.DOORSnO(112) AS "DOOR NO"

   -- The Functions are
   CREATE FUNCTION DOORSnO(@ID INT)
   RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
   AS
   BEGIN
   DECLARE @ADDRESS AS VARCHAR(100)
   DECLARE @I AS INT = 1
    DECLARE @DOORS AS VARCHAR(10) =''

    SET @ADDRESS = (SELECT ADDRESS FROM DEMO WHERE ID = @ID)

    WHILE SUBSTRING(@ADDRESS, @I, 1) <> ' '
    BEGIN
        SET @DOORS += SUBSTRING(@ADDRESS, @I, 1)    
        SET @I = @I +1
    END
    RETURN @DOORS
   END
```

Comment: Creating a looping function to select data you have already available is really bad code, the loop is not even needed. You can use the address as parameter for the function instead and avoid a select for each row. There are more effective ways of finding the door number, read some of the other answers to see how

Comment: i agree that, select for each row is bad practice, and i agree too that passing address as parameter also very effective in terms of speed, but why loop is bad??